# Basic HTML Wordpress: Position two images next to each other

Tags: html, wordpress

I have created an entry page in my WordPress blog. I am trying to place two images next to each other (see below the images in the code snippet). These images contains the same link. For some reason my two images are not being placed next to each other. Second image is placed under the first one. What am I doing wrong? I show here a piece of the code where my problem occurs:

```
<h4>Disadvantages</h4>
<ul>
    <li>Nothing</li>
</ul>
<h2><a href="http://www.third-party-company.com/home?ref=john" 
     target="_blank" rel="noopener">Dollar</a></h2>
     <a href="http://www.third-party-company.com/home?ref=john" 
        target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img class="img-responsive"
        src="http://www.third-party-company.com/images/banners/11.gif"
        max-width="468" max-height="60" border="0" />
        <img src="http://www.myUser.byethost7.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/RegisterButton.png" alt="Register Button" width="280" height="180" /></a>
    BlablablablablablablaBlablablablablablablaBlablablablablablablaBlablablabla
 blablablaBlablablablablablablaBlablablablablablablaBlablablablablablablaBla
 blablablablablablaBlablablablablablabla
<ul>
    <li>Point 1</li>
    <li>Point 2</li>
</ul>
```

There are not whitespaces. Also I have reduced the last image, RegisterButton, to check that the problem is not due to line length exceeds.

Comment: Read the documentation, img-responsive class displays elements as block elements so they appear stacked.  https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp

Comment: @AndrewSchultz Ok, thanks for the documentation, so then if it displays elements as a block elements what I need to do in order my two images appear next to each other?

Comment: Override the CSS to display the images inline.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz and is there any way to solve this without removing css?

Comment: Either you override the CSS via inline styling on the img tag or you override the bootstrap CSS via a stylesheet.  The other option is to not load the Bootstrap CSS file at all but then then 'img-responsive' class won't work anymore.